# Line 134 1119: Access of possibly undefined property xspeed through a reference with static type enemy_mc

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I'm new to the flash programming world, and I am working through Flash Game Development by example and I'm having an issue with one of the games.

The assignment is AstroPanic, and I thought it would be fun to make it DBZ style. My issue is when I try to compile now, I get an error.

```
package  
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var spaceship:spaceship_mc= new spaceship_mc();
    private var isFiring:Boolean=false;
    private var bullet:bullet_mc;
    private const BULLET_SPEED:uint=10;
    private var enemy=enemy_mc;
    private var level:uint=1;
    private var enemyVector:Vector.<enemy_mc>=new Vector.<enemy_mc>();

    private var prevX:int = 0;
    private var curX:int = 0;
    private var dirX:int = 0;

    public function Main() 
    {
        placeSpaceship();
        for (var i:uint=1; i<level+3; i++)
        {
            placeEnemy(i);
        }
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrm);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onMouseCk);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, CheckDirection);

    }//END Main function

    private function placeSpaceship():void 
    {
        spaceship=new spaceship_mc();
        addChild(spaceship);
        spaceship.y=430;
        spaceship.gotoAndStop(1);
    }

    private function onEnterFrm(e:Event):void 
    {
        spaceship.x=mouseX;

        if (spaceship.x<30) 
        {
            spaceship.x=30;
        }
        if (spaceship.x>610) 
        {
            spaceship.x=610;
        }
        if (isFiring) 
        {
            bullet.y-=BULLET_SPEED;
            if (bullet.y<0) 
            {
            removeChild(bullet);
            bullet=null;
            isFiring=false;
            }
        }
        enemyVector.forEach(manageEnemy);
    }//END onEnterFrm

    function CheckDirection(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        spaceship.gotoAndPlay(GetHorizontalDirection());         
        e.updateAfterEvent();
    }//END checkdirection

    function GetHorizontalDirection():int
    {
        prevX = curX;
        curX = stage.mouseX;

        if (prevX > curX) 
        {
        dirX = 16;
        } 
        else if (prevX < curX) 
        {
        dirX = 9;
        } 
        else 
        {
        dirX = 1;
        }

        return dirX;
    }

    private function onMouseCk(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        if (! isFiring) 
        {
            spaceship.gotoAndPlay(2);
            placeBullet();
            isFiring=true;
        }
    }

    private function placeBullet():void
    {
        bullet=new bullet_mc();
        addChild(bullet);
        bullet.x=spaceship.x;
        bullet.y=400;

    }//END placeBullet

    public function placeEnemy(enemy_level:uint):void 
    {
        enemy=new enemy_mc();
        enemy.x=Math.random()*500+70;
        enemy.y=Math.random()*200+50;
        enemy.gotoAndStop(1);
        addChild(enemy);
        var dir:Number = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;
        enemy.xspeed=enemy_level*Math.cos(dir);
        enemy.xspeed=enemy_level*Math.sin(dir);
        enemyVector.push(enemy);
    }//END placeEnemy

    private function manageEnemy(c:enemy_mc,index:int,v:Vector.<enemy_mc>):void 
    {
        var currentEnemy:enemy_mc = c;

        currentEnemy.x+=currentEnemy.xspeed; // Line 134 1119: Access of possibly undefined property xspeed through a reference with static type enemy_mc
        currentEnemy.y+=currentEnemy.yspeed;
        if (currentEnemy.x<25) 
        {
            currentEnemy.x=25;
            currentEnemy.xspeed*=-1;
        }
        if (currentEnemy.x>615) 
        {
            currentEnemy.x=615;
            currentEnemy.xspeed*=-1;
        }
        if (currentEnemy.y<25) 
        {
            currentEnemy.y=25;
            currentEnemy.yspeed*=-1;
        }
        if (currentEnemy.y>455) 
        {
            currentEnemy.y=455;
            currentEnemy.yspeed*=-1;
        }
    }//END manageEnemy
}//END Class

}
```

Enemy Class

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class enemy_mc extends MovieClip
{

    public function enemy_mc() 
    {
        // constructor code
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Line is 134, where the manageEnemy has this:
    currentEnemy.x+=currentEnemy.xspeed;

Comment: @Mark Rivinius It's better like that...

Answer (score 0):

This error message of your compiler means that the `property` xspeed of your `class` enemy_mc is not defined. You have first to define this property in your class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class enemy_mc extends MovieClip
    {
        public var xspeed:Number;
        public var yspeed:Number;

        public function enemy_mc()
        {
            // constructor code
        }
    }
}
```